# How to disable the default context menu of pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

Can anyone help me to disable the context menu of pyqtgraph or remove some options from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [PlotItem.setMenuEnabled](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotItem.setMenuEnabled) method. Something like:

```
    self.plot = pg.PlotItem()
    self.plot.setMenuEnabled(False)
```

I have not found a way to remove options from it but perhaps it's possible. I would be interested in this as well.

Answer (score 9):

I've been working on this myself and this is what I've found (as of May 2021). For reference, the image below is the right click menu that appears for the PyQtGraph PlotWidget, but not all of the items (QActions) are added by the PlotWidget itself.

[image: PlotWidget right click menu]

- The menu items above the separator are created by the ViewBox menu (source code [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ViewBox/ViewBox.html?highlight=viewboxmenu)) which can be accessed through `PlotItem.vb` or `PlotItem.getViewBox()` (if you have a `PlotWidget`, you can get the `PlotItem` through `PlotWidget.getPlotItem()`). The menu items (`QAction`s) can be accessed through `PlotItem.vb.menu.actions()` (Qt reference [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html)) and can be removed by checking the `QAction.text()` to find the `QAction` you want to change or remove.
- `PlotItem` (source code [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/PlotItem/PlotItem.html#PlotItem)) creates a menu called `ctrlMenu`, which contains the plot options (e.g. Transform, Downsample). This is the "Plot Options" submenu in the image above, and does not appear in the `PlotItem.vb.menu.actions()` but can be accessed via `PlotItem.ctrlMenu.menuAction()` ([StackOverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703310/10342097)).
- The "Export..." option comes from the underlying `GraphicsScene` (source code [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/GraphicsScene/GraphicsScene.html#GraphicsScene)) and can be accessed via `ViewBox.scene().contextMenu[0]` which gives the "Export..." QAction.
- Any of the `QAction` can be hidden/shown by `QAction.setVisible()` ([Qt reference](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qaction.html))

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to edit & remove the options, check this out:
[ViewBoxMenu](https://gitlab.tuebingen.mpg.de/elacosse/vviewer/blob/66450685a71f76f5fefa5481addf933d6d687113/vviewer/pyqtgraphmod/graphicsItems/ViewBox/ViewBoxMenu.py)

remove the Export... Options is found here:
[Export...  (contextMenu)](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/GraphicsScene/GraphicsScene.html#GraphicsScene)

i just cleared the list:

```
export = self.gui.Display.ui.graphicsView.sceneObj.contextMenu
del export[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

In practice to implement Elliot's answer I would subclass `Viewbox`, after the initialization you can hide the action of the default `ViewBoxMenu` which you don't want to use. Then you can add your own actions to the `self.menu`.

Below I hide the "X-axis" option and add a submenu to the default `ViewBox` contextual menu to change the background color.

```
plot = pg.PlotWidget(title="New Menu",viewBox=NewViewBox())
```

```
class NewViewBox(pg.ViewBox):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
            super(NewViewBox, self).__init__(parent)

            self.myMenuEdit() 

        def myMenuEdit(self):
            #Hide Default Actions
            MenusToHide = ["X axis"] #Names of menus to hide
            w = self.menu.actions()
            for m in w:
                for mhs in MenusToHide:
                    if (m.text().startswith(mhs)):
                        m.setVisible(False)
                        break

            #AddMySubMenu
            leftMenu = self.menu.addMenu("Background color")
            group = QtGui.QActionGroup(self)
            Yellow = QtGui.QAction(u'Yellow', group)
            Red = QtGui.QAction(u'Red', group)
            leftMenu.addActions(group.actions())
            Yellow.setCheckable(True)
            Red.setCheckable(True)
            group.triggered.connect(self.setBgColor)
            self.bgActions=[Yellow,Red]




        def setBgColor(self, action):
              mode = None
              if action == self.bgActions[0]:
                  self.setBackgroundColor("y")
              elif action == self.bgActions[1]:
                  self.setBackgroundColor("r")
```

Note that each parent of the `ViewBox` which has a method `getContextMenus` has its own menu options and they will be loaded and added to the menu at each click through the call of `self.scene().addParentContextMenus(self, menu, ev)` in the function `raiseContextMenu`.

`PlotItem`, for example, adds Export and Plot Options. You can override the menus of each of those parental classes if needed.